# Why won't flexbox center my image like the other elements within the div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I am trying to center `#login-logo` within the `#login-content` div with flexbox, but the image is the only thing not centered. I thought `text-align:center` would take care of it.

The form, the button, and the paragraph in the same div are all styled exactly how I want them -stacked on top of each other and centered horizontally and vertically.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: url("images/newnewgirls.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container2 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding img {
  width: 55%;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#login-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#login-content {
  height: 80%;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.login-input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 1.5rem auto;
}

#login-logo {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="32x32" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resolve.css">
  <title>Resolve - Real Women, Real Feedback</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" alt="resolvelogo"></a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <li><a href="indexresolve.html">Home</a></li>
        < <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button></li>
          <div id="login-modal">
            <div id="login-content">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img id="login-logo" src="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
              <form>
                <input class="login-input" type="text" placeholder="username">
                <input class="login-input" type="password" placeholder="password">
                <button>Log In</button>
              </form>
              <p>By clicking log in, you agree to our <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>, <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>, and our <a href="cookie.html">Cookie Policy</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container2">
      <div>
        <h1>Guys</h1>
        <h2>fajfsda klfsdajfodisjflkd oisdjfklewjf oisdjfsakfj akfjfslkdja;fj sd;akfjdkfjsdakfj saifjsdakfs.</h2>
        <button>Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Ladies</h1>
        <h2>dklasdjfs kdsjdlk jfsalkjf las;fjdaa fdaksjdk skjfsidjf akldfjskl fjsdlkfjskdlfjsdifjdkf dkfjsdijf s </h2>
        <button id="login">Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div class="appad">
        <h2>App Coming Soon!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="resolve.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try`margin:0 auto` for your `#login-logo` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `align-items: center;` to the `#login-content`

```
#login-content {
  height: 80%;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the logo in center, by just adding margin property as:

```
#login-logo {
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a *column* `flexbox` to align *horizontally*, you can use `align-items: center` to the *logo* in the `#login-content` container - see demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: url("images/newnewgirls.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container2 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding img {
  width: 55%;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#login-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#login-content {
  height: 80%;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center; /* ADDED */
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.login-input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 1.5rem auto;
}

#login-logo {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="32x32" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resolve.css">
  <title>Resolve - Real Women, Real Feedback</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" alt="resolvelogo"></a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <li><a href="indexresolve.html">Home</a></li>
        < <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button></li>
          <div id="login-modal">
            <div id="login-content">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img id="login-logo" src="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
              <form>
                <input class="login-input" type="text" placeholder="username">
                <input class="login-input" type="password" placeholder="password">
                <button>Log In</button>
              </form>
              <p>By clicking log in, you agree to our <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>, <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>, and our <a href="cookie.html">Cookie Policy</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container2">
      <div>
        <h1>Guys</h1>
        <h2>fajfsda klfsdajfodisjflkd oisdjfklewjf oisdjfsakfj akfjfslkdja;fj sd;akfjdkfjsdakfj saifjsdakfs.</h2>
        <button>Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Ladies</h1>
        <h2>dklasdjfs kdsjdlk jfsalkjf las;fjdaa fdaksjdk skjfsidjf akldfjskl fjsdlkfjskdlfjsdifjdkf dkfjsdijf s </h2>
        <button id="login">Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div class="appad">
        <h2>App Coming Soon!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="resolve.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `align-items: center`, which will center the flex items (your `flex-direction` is `column`)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: url("images/newnewgirls.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container2 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding img {
  width: 55%;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#login-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#login-content {
  height: 80%;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.login-input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 1.5rem auto;
}

#login-logo {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="32x32" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resolve.css">
  <title>Resolve - Real Women, Real Feedback</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" alt="resolvelogo"></a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <li><a href="indexresolve.html">Home</a></li>
        < <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button></li>
          <div id="login-modal">
            <div id="login-content">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img id="login-logo" src="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
              <form>
                <input class="login-input" type="text" placeholder="username">
                <input class="login-input" type="password" placeholder="password">
                <button>Log In</button>
              </form>
              <p>By clicking log in, you agree to our <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>, <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>, and our <a href="cookie.html">Cookie Policy</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container2">
      <div>
        <h1>Guys</h1>
        <h2>fajfsda klfsdajfodisjflkd oisdjfklewjf oisdjfsakfj akfjfslkdja;fj sd;akfjdkfjsdakfj saifjsdakfs.</h2>
        <button>Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Ladies</h1>
        <h2>dklasdjfs kdsjdlk jfsalkjf las;fjdaa fdaksjdk skjfsidjf akldfjskl fjsdlkfjskdlfjsdifjdkf dkfjsdijf s </h2>
        <button id="login">Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div class="appad">
        <h2>App Coming Soon!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="resolve.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That works, but why were the other items already centered horizontally? Wouldn't my text-align:center have worked for the image as well? It worked for the button I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your image in a div for the flex to apply correctly to it like in the code bellow.

An alternative would also be add :

```
align-self: center
```

to the image itself

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

html, body{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:100%;
}

body{
 min-height:100%;
 min-width:100%;
 background: url("images/newnewgirls.jpg");
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 position:relative;
 
}
.container{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.container2{
 width:80%;
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
}

header{
 padding:1em;
 margin:0;
}
header #branding{
 float:left;
}

header #branding img{
 width:55%;
}


header nav{
 float:right;
 margin-top:0.5em;
}

header nav li{
 display:inline;
 padding:1em;
}

header nav li a{
 text-decoration:none;
}

#login-modal{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 text-align:center;

}

#login-content{
 height:80%;
 width:25%;
 position:relative;
 background-color:white;
 border-radius:2%;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content:center;
 text-align:center;
}

.close{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:5%;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.login-input{
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto 1.5rem auto;
}

#login-logo{
 height:3rem;
 width:3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="32x32" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resolve.css">
 <title>Resolve - Real Women, Real Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <div  id="branding">
    <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" alt="resolvelogo"></a>
   </div>
   <nav>
    <li><a href="indexresolve.html">Home</a></li><
    <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button></li>
    <div id="login-modal">
     <div id="login-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <div id="login-logo-container">
      <img id="login-logo" src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/overlays/smallsquaretile.png">
            </div>
      <form>
       <input class ="login-input" type="text" placeholder="username" >
       <input class ="login-input" type="password" placeholder="password">
       <button>Log In</button>
      </form>
      <p>By clicking log in, you agree to our <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>, <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>, and
      our <a href="cookie.html">Cookie Policy</a>.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav> 
  </header>
 <section>
  <div class="container2">
   <div>
    <h1>Guys</h1>
    <h2>fajfsda klfsdajfodisjflkd oisdjfklewjf oisdjfsakfj akfjfslkdja;fj sd;akfjdkfjsdakfj saifjsdakfs.</h2>
    <button>Get Started</button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Ladies</h1>
    <h2>dklasdjfs kdsjdlk jfsalkjf las;fjdaa fdaksjdk skjfsidjf akldfjskl fjsdlkfjskdlfjsdifjdkf dkfjsdijf s  </h2>
    <button id="login">Get Started</button>
   </div>
   <div class="appad">
    <h2>App Coming Soon!</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="resolve.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That does work! But why would I have to wrap the image in a div for flexbox to work, but not for the other elements?